# Framework7 - Unable to redirect to a different view

Tags: html-framework-7

I am really lost with Framework 7, I find it quite difficult to work with as 
    I cannot find the information I am looking for in the doc(in an easy way).

```
I only want to redirect the user to a different view which is here 
pages/login.html after my ajax call as:

500: function (response) { //error
      app.dialog.close();
      console.log("error 500");
     //This does not work
      resolve({
        componentUrl: './pages/login.html',
      })

I tried this but it does not work:
path: ‘/login/’,
url: ‘./pages/login.html’,
```

Have anyone a bit of experience with this framework please?

https://framework7.io/vue/navigation-router.html

Thank you,

Comment: can u make jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this methods: `return app.router.navigate('/yourbooking/');` or 
`return app.views.main.router.navigate('/');`

Here navigate methods first argument is the path you give in route.js file.

example:

```
{
    path:'/yourbooking/',
    componentUrl:'./pages/yourbooking.html',

},
```

for your case it should be like this:

```
app.request.post('../authenticate.php/', {
            userdata: userdata,
        }, function (success) {

            console.log(success);

            return app.views.main.router.navigate('/login/');
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("error");

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
app.router.navigate('/login/');
```